# Read battery voltage for external RTC on STM32

Tags: stm32, battery-operated, rtc

I am using STM32F446RE for my application to just log the time accurately. I have an RTC module [DS3231SN](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/609/DS3231-3122489.pdf) connected to the STM32 on the I2C. The RTC is connected to a coin cell battery [CR2032](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000650957DS02/datenblatt-650957-varta-lithium-coin-cr2032-bli-1-knopfzelle-cr-2032-lithium-230-mah-3-v-1-st.pdf) for a long life on its VBAT terminal. The entire board by itself is powered with an external 5V. However, the device is expected to last for 10 years and the device is powered on roughly for 2000h.

1. How much life can I estimate from a 230mAh battery? The datasheet mentions the different current drawn but I cannot say for sure how long the device is powered with the external 5V rail. Is the IBATTC used even though I am not using the temperature data in my code?
   [image: datasheet]
2. What is the best way to keep track of the status of the coin cell battery? I have connected the STM32 VBAT pin to the coin cell battery. The minimum supply voltage for the RTC is 2.3V. So, does that mean if the battery voltage drops to 2.3V, the RTC shuts down when there is no external 5V supplied?
3. I want to design an LED indicator for the battery status with the following states:
   3.0V - 2.75V = State 1 (Battery OK)
   2.75V - 2.5V = State 2
   2.5V - 2.3V = State 3
   <2.3V = State 4 (Battery fail)
   I can read the battery voltage from the VBAT pin on the STM32. Is the voltage read a linear relation with the battery capacity?

[image: Basic circuit]

Comment: Sounds weird. If you have an external RTC chip, why would you use the back-up battery for the MCU built-in RTC too? If you connect same battery to both RTC chip and MCU, the MCU will also draw some current from the battery. And even connecting it to MCU ADC pin might have leakage currents, especially if MCU is powered off. If you connect battery to MCU VBAT, you might as well use MCU built-in RTC. What do you want the system to do and how?

Comment: @Justme I did test with the internal RTC but it had too much of a drift for my application. Like I mentioned, I need this to operate for many years and this RTC module seems to be the really accurate, especially in the large temperature gradients. This is for a soil humidity logger with timestamps. When there is no main power supply to the MCU, there is no activity happening there. The VBAT pin is used only to read the voltage levels of the battery while the device is operating. (2000h life)

Comment: @Justme is the VBAT pin on the MCU draining current even if I do not use the internal RTC?

Comment: @dreamcoder Table 29 of the datasheet of the MCU: typically 0.05 µA at 25 °C, max 2 µA at 85 °C and 4 µA at 105 °C.